# Type Mismatch - 1st argument to sandbox is not what I expect

Tags: typeerror, elm, elm-architecture

I am trying to add subscriptions as I have a dropdown, this helps ensure that the dropdowns automatically close when you click outside of them. On doing so, I had to change the `model` as well as my `update`.

This [**link**](http://elm-bootstrap.info/dropdown) (will take you to the Elm Bootstrap site) is the dropdown I am working with which is using Bootstrap 4.

**Error I am getting**

> The 1st argument to `sandbox` is not what I expect:
>
> 295|     Browser.sandbox 296|>        { init = initialModel 297|>
>   , update = update 298|>        , view = view 299|>        }
>
> This argument is a record of type:
>
> ```
> { init : ( Model, Cmd Msg )
> , update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
> , view : Model -> Html Msg
> }
> ```
>
> But `sandbox` needs the 1st argument to be:
>
> ```
> { init : ( Model, Cmd Msg )
> , update : Msg -> ( Model, Cmd Msg ) -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
> , view : ( Model, Cmd Msg ) -> Html Msg
> }
> ```

**Alias Model**

```
type alias Model =
    { currentNumber : Int, clicks : Int, outputList : List(String), uniqueValues : Dict Int Int, firstNumber : String, secondNumber : String, myDropState : Dropdown.State, items : List String, selectedItem : String, dictKeyToRemove : String,
    modalVisibility : Modal.Visibility  }
```

**Initial Model**

```
initialModel : (Model, Cmd Msg)
initialModel =
    ({ currentNumber = 0, clicks = 0, outputList = [""], uniqueValues = Dict.empty, firstNumber = "", secondNumber = "", myDropState = Dropdown.initialState, items = ["Small", "Medium", "Large"], selectedItem = "Small", dictKeyToRemove = "",
    modalVisibility = Modal.hidden }, Cmd.none)
```

**Main**

```
main : Program () Model Msg
main =
    Browser.sandbox
        { init = initialModel           
        , update = update      
        , view = view   
        }
```

**Subscriptions**

```
subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
    Sub.batch
        [ Dropdown.subscriptions model.myDropState DropMsg ]
```

**Update**

```
update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg)
update msg model =
    case msg of   
        DropMsg state ->
            ({model | myDropState = state }, Cmd.none)
```

I am not sure what I am missing at this point, I have tried changing the argument with no luck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Browser.sandbox` will create a simple and very limited program. The dropdown requires capabilities beyond that, namely subscriptions, which means you need to use either `Browser.element` or `Browser.document` instead.

The type of `Browser.element` is:

```elm
element :
    { init : flags -> ( model, Cmd msg )
    , view : model -> Html msg
    , update : msg -> model -> ( model, Cmd msg )
    , subscriptions : model -> Sub msg
    }
    -> Program flags model msg
```

Compared to `Browser.sandbox`:

```elm
sandbox :
    { init : model
    , view : model -> Html msg
    , update : msg -> model -> model
    }
    -> Program () model msg
```

There are three differences here:

1. `init` takes an argument, `flags`, which can be anything and will be interpreted by the runtime according to its type. For your purpose just using `()` should be enough (which is essentially what `sandbox` does), but see [the flags section of the guide](https://guide.elm-lang.org/interop/flags.html) for more details.
2. `init` and `update` returns `( model, Cmd msg )` instead of just `model`.  This is the root cause of your error, because you have `update` and `init` functions which return `( model, Cmd msg )` as `element` would expect, but try to feed them to `sandbox`. This makes the compiler unhappy, because it thinks that `model` should be `( Model, Cmd msg )` instead of just `Model`.
3. `element` expects an additional `subscriptions` function, which you have defined but currently aren't doing anything with since sandbox doesn't accept it.

Putting this all together, substituting the following `main` function should work for you:

```
main : Program () Model Msg
main =
    Browser.element
        { init = \() -> initialModel           
        , update = update      
        , view = view
        , subscriptions = subscriptions  
        }
```